# How to check the most number of the same elements next to each other?

Tags: python, algorithm

So, I have a string which contains ONLY 0 and 1. What I want to do is to check the least number of the same elements next to each other, so when it's '01010011' number = 2 (two times 1 and two times 0), when '0101010' number = 1, when '01111111000000111100000101000011111' number = 4 etc.
One more thing I can assume - there always will be the same smallest number of 0's and 1's. That's what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
bits = '1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011'

y = 0
x = 100
for i in range(len(bits) - 1):
    if list(bits[i]) == list(bits[i+1]) and list(bits[i]) == ["1"]:
        if y == 0 and x > 1:
            y += 2
            x = 99
        else:
            y += 1
    elif x == 100 and ["1"] in (list(bits[i]), list(bits[i+1])):
        x = 1
        break
    else:
        if 0 < x > y > 0:
            x = y
        y = 0
```

Comment: Did you mean only 0 and 1s (instead of 1 and 2s)? Also, "'010111100010000111' number = 4" is not quite, there are 3 0s and 3 1s?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I said 1 and 2. And you're right about the second thing, I had a stroke or something while writing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fun solution using regex:

```py
import re
min(map(len, re.findall(r'0{2,}|1{2,}', bits)))
```

Explanation:

- `0{2,}` finds all substrings with 2 consecutive 0s or more
- `1{2,}` finds all substrings with 2 consecutive 1s or more
- `0{2,}|1{2,}` finds either of those criteria
- `re.findall` returns all found consecutive digits in a list
- `map(len, lst)` applies `len` function to each element in the list `lst`
- `min` finds the smallest value, i.e. the length of the shortest consecutive-digit string found.

Answer (score 4):

If its only 0s and 1s:

```
len(max(max(bits.split('0'),  key=len), max(bits.split('1'), key=len), key=len))
```

Time and space complexity is `O(N)`.

The idea to split based on '0's and then '1's is pretty apparent. This will give you two lists that have contiguous 0's and empty strings, and 1's and empty strings, respectively. We take the largest len out of both the lists.

I posted the above answer only because I find it a fun 1-liner. You can/should do better in Space complexity, i.e. `O(1)` by

1. Looping over the string
2. Incrementing a local variable for number of same chars seen so far and updating the maximum value seen in the process
3. Resetting the local counter once a different char is encountered, i.e. once the continuity breaks.

Comment: Some explanation of your code might help the OP understand it.

Comment: the question asks for the shortest substring satisfying the condition, not the longest.